# Problems with a background 100% height in bootstrap framework

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this piece of code with bootstrap:

```
<style>
#restaurants {
overflow: hidden;
}

#restaurantsbg {
background-image: url('images/bg.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
min-height: 100%;
}
</style>

<section id="restaurants">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="restaurantstxt" class="col-md-6"></div>
            <div id="restaurantsbg" class="col-md-6"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And basically what i want to do is to have a background image in #restaurantsbg according to #restaurants height.

The code above does not work, any idea what can i do?

Regards!

Comment: DIVs are empty, you cannot view your background if you don't fill them or set an height

Comment: #restaurants, html, body, .container and .row must be `hieght:100%` too

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need something like this, please click in full page to see it:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
  #restaurants {
    border: 1px  solid #000;
    height: 200px;
  }

  #restaurantsbg{
    background-image: url('http://bligoo.com/media/users/0/32886/images/Advertencia.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size:cover;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    border: 1px  solid #000;
  }
  </style>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <section id="restaurants">
      <div id="restaurantstxt" class="col-md-6"></div>
      <div id="restaurantsbg" class="col-md-6"></div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```